# Use GC in listener method

Tags: java, events, view, swt, mouselistener

I have created a custom view using [this](https://eclipse.org/articles/viewArticle/ViewArticle2.html) tutorial. I am able to draw everything I want inside the `paintControl()` method. What I want to do, is to have a `MouseMoveListener` besides my `PaintListener`, which should draw some additinal stuff on mouseover:

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.NONE);
    canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            // draw something
        }
    });

    canvas.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMove(MouseEvent e) {
            system.out.println(e.x + ", e.y");
            // draw something
        }
    });
}
```

Is it possible to use `GC` inside the `mouseMove()` method, to draw shapes in addition to the existing shapes, created in `paintControl()`? I tried to set `GC` as instance variable and set it in `paintControl()` to reuse it in `mouseOver()` but unfortunately it is `null` on that point.

Comment: You should not use GC drawing outside of paintEvents. You want drawing on canvas after left mouse button pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kuba sais, you cannot draw on a GC outside a `PaintEvent`.

To cause the canvas to be redrawn, call its `redraw` method form the mouse event like so:

```
canvas.addMouseMoveListener( new MouseMoveListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseMove( MouseEvent event ) {
      canvas.redraw();
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

To draw on any control (that is drawable, extends `Drawable`) you need to create an instance of `GC` and use that to draw whatever you need. Don't forget to dispose the `GC` instance though.

I have modified the [Snippet10](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet10.java) to show how to do this:

```java
private static boolean mouseDown = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Advanced Graphics");
    FontData fd = shell.getFont().getFontData()[0];
    final Font font = new Font(display, fd.getName(), 60, SWT.BOLD | SWT.ITALIC);
    final Image image = new Image(display, 640, 480);
    final Rectangle rect = image.getBounds();
    GC gc = new GC(image);
    gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
    gc.fillOval(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    gc.dispose();
    shell.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            GC gc = event.gc;               
            Transform tr = new Transform(display);
            tr.translate(50, 120);
            tr.rotate(-30);
            gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0, rect.width, rect.height, 0, 0, rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2);
            gc.setAlpha(100);
            gc.setTransform(tr);
            Path path = new Path(display);
            path.addString("SWT", 0, 0, font);
            gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));
            gc.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
            gc.fillPath(path);
            gc.drawPath(path);
            tr.dispose();
            path.dispose();
        }           
    });
    shell.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDown = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDown = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {}
    });
    shell.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMove(MouseEvent e) {
            if (!mouseDown)
                return;

            GC gc = new GC(shell);
            gc.drawPoint(e.x, e.y);
            gc.dispose();
        }
    });

    shell.setSize(shell.computeSize(rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2));
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    image.dispose();
    font.dispose();
    display.dispose();
}
```

**NOTE**: that whenever paint event is fired on the control, your custom drawings would be lost. So perhaps it is better to draw on an image. And then call redraw on the control, which always assumes that it has to draw its background, and then draw that image over the background. This way, on every redraw you can maintain your mouse drawing.

Comment: You could also save your mouse coordinates in an array. And use those coordinates to draw points, paths or polygons as needed in the paint even of the control.